# Crawling sites with certain domain suffix

Tags: http, web, web-crawler, domain-name

I am interested in finding as much domain names as possible that have a given domain suffix that I am interested in, for instance: ".com", ".net", ".org", etc.

I tried to crawl Google, but it obviuosly isn't legal and is hard to do.

Does there exist a large list with domain names? If not, how can I make a crawler that finds as much as possible domain names that end with a given domain suffix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CommonCrawl have recently announced the publication of [a ranked list of hosts][2] (385M in total), which you could filter by domain suffix.

Comment: Thanks, man. Sometimes it's better to use other's effort instead of crawling sites yourself. I will mark this as an answer because it helped my case.